# $A.createComponent throwing error when trying to create the same component for second time

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, dynamic, javascript-controller

I have to add and remove components from a Modal dialog - so using

add code:

```
$A.createComponent("pbrdev:TransactionViewer",
                           {
                               thistrans: component.getReference("v.thistrans"),
                               currencies: component.getReference("v.currencies"),
                               tdetails: component.getReference("v.thisdetails")
                           }, 
                           function(tranvwr){ 
                               if (component.isValid()) { 
                                   component.set("v.body", tranvwr); 
                               } 
                           });
```

and remove code

```
component.set("v.body","");
```

this works fine on the first call but getting this error on second call to add

```
Abstract component without provider def cannot be instantiated : markup://force:inputField : undefined
```

the component being created/added is pure markup and contains no javascript or css.

**Update:** This error only happens if the component contains any of the force: fields, like force:inputField, force:outputField, etc. When using simple ui: fields or html fields only, this error doesn't happen.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by second call ? Are you getting error when adding multiple of them ?

Comment: The component is being added in modal popup. Component will be added on each "show" and removed on each "hide". As the same modal frame is used for various actions. First time any component is is added, it rendered fine - but if the same action is invoked again - I am trying to make the same call to add the component and then it fails. All subsequent adds are failing.

Comment: @Bhuvan Did you happen to find a solution for your problem? We're experiencing the exact same behavior.

Comment: @Folkert - Looks like Summer16 breaks all force:xxx components. So switched over to ui:xxx components and everything works fine. For lookups I used Tony Scott's LookupSObject component with some changes. This all worked out pretty well.